# Value of type 'SecondViewController' has no member 'bmiValue' I'm getting this issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm getting an error " Value of type 'SecondViewController' has no member 'bmiValue'  "
I'm trying to find out what's wrong with the code

import UIKit

```
        class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var heightLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var weightLabel: UILabel!
        @IBAction func weightSliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        weightLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", sender.value)
        }
        @IBAction func heightSliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        heightLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", sender.value)
        }

        @IBAction func calculatePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let weight = weightSliderValue.value
        let height = heightSliderValue.value

        let bmi = weight/pow(height, 2)
        print(bmi)

        let secondVc = SecondViewController() Value of type 'SecondViewController' has no member 'bmiValue'
        secondVc.bmiValue = String(format: ".1f", bmi)

        self.present(secondVc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        @IBOutlet weak var weightSliderValue: UISlider!
        @IBOutlet weak var heightSliderValue: UISlider!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }


        }
```

here is the code for second view controller where I want to display bmi

import UIKit

```
var bmiValue = 0.0

class SecondViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Hello"
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50)
        view.addSubview(label)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn man, put var inside a class, not as global value. Swift 101.

Comment: @Prettygeek more like programming 101

Comment: Now I'm getting this error "Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'Double' " whereas I've already tried to change the value from float to string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass a value as a String, the var / property you are setting must also be a String:

```
class SecondViewController : UIViewController {

    // if you want to pass a string
    var bmiValue: String = "0.0"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Hello"
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50)
        view.addSubview(label)
        
    }
}
```

Now, in your "main" view controller, you can do this:

```
    let secondVc = SecondViewController()
    secondVc.bmiValue = String(format: ".1f", bmi)
    
    self.present(secondVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: @glazeboy - be sure to mark the answer "Accepted" for the benefit of other users who may come across your question.